# Query or Stored Proc to get points defining a polygon/multipolygon

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I have a SQL Server 2012 table with a geography type column which contains either a polygon or multipolygon.  Some of the multipolygons have holes in them.  I would like a query or stored procedure that gets all of the points that define the shape, along with which ring of a multipolygon the point belongs to.

Note that some of these shapes have thousands of points, which could create a problem using a recursive CTE.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also trying to get all the points that define a polygon.

Comment: #Evan, yes but I wrote code instead, see the answer.

Comment: Cool, looks like you just parse the string. That is what I was going to resort to also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a query or stored procedure to do this, I wrote code.  I'm using Entity Framework and SchoolDistrict is the object for the table in SQL Server.  DistrictLocation is the geography type field.  Here's the code I used to get that which is in VB.NET.  It returns a list of coordinate sets, each of which is a ring in the multipolygon.

```
Public Function SchoolDistrictVertices() As List(Of List(Of Coordinate))
If SchoolDistrict Is Nothing OrElse SchoolDistrict.DistrictLocation Is Nothing Then
  Return Nothing
Else
  'get the points that define the shape by parsing the shape's WKT
  Dim result = New List(Of List(Of Coordinate))
  Dim wkt = SchoolDistrict.DistrictLocation.Location.WellKnownValue().WellKnownText
  Dim startPos = wkt.IndexOf("((")

  Do Until startPos = -1
    Dim list = New List(Of Coordinate)
    Dim endPos = wkt.IndexOf(")", startPos)
    Dim piece = wkt.Substring(startPos + 1, endPos - (startPos + 1))
    Dim coords = piece.Split(","c)

    For Each item In coords
      item = item.Trim().Replace("(", "")
      Dim parts = item.Split(" "c)
      Dim lng = parts(0)
      Dim lat = parts(1)
      Dim coord = New Coordinate()
      coord.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(lat)
      coord.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(lng)

      list.Add(coord)
    Next
    result.Add(list)

    startPos = wkt.IndexOf("(", endPos)
  Loop

  Return result
End If
End Function

Public Structure Coordinate
  Public Property Latitude As Double
  Public Property Longitude As Double
End Structure
```